# Substract 5 months from a date in perl

Tags: perl, date, datetime, calendar

I need to substract 5 months from the current date in perl.
for example:

2014-01-30 - 5month = 2013-08-30

It should be accurate in calculating months with differnet lengths for example february.

Greets, Max.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do this is to use [Badger::Timestamp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Badger%3a%3aTimestamp)

```
use Badger::Timestamp ;

 my $stamp = Badger::Timestamp->new(
    year    => 2014,
    month   => 1,
    day     => 30
 );
 $stamp->adjust( months => -5  );
 print "Adjusted time stamp is : $stamp \n" ;
```